Twilio Trial Account: Cannot Verify Phone Number via SMS and Error 400 (Code 21608)
I am currently using a Twilio trial account to test SMS functionality. To send messages to other phone numbers, I need to verify those numbers first. However, I am encountering two issues:
When verifying a phone number via SMS, I do not receive the verification SMS, even after waiting a long time. (Note: Since this is a trial account, I cannot use the "Call" option for verification.)
When I try sending an SMS from the Twilio Console's "Send an SMS" (Messaging -> Try It Out), or programmatically using the following code:
  from twilio.rest import Client

    account_sid = 'my_account_sid'
    auth_token = '[AuthToken]'
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    message = client.messages.create(
    from_='+16282598XXX',  # My Twilio-provided number
    body='Hello world',
    to='+840708504XXX'     # The phone number I registered with Twilio (already verified)
     )
    print(message.sid)



I get the following error:
{
    "code": 21608,
    "message": "The number +84070850XXXX is unverified. Trial accounts cannot send messages to unverified numbers; verify +84070850XXXX at twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/verified, or purchase a Twilio number to send messages to unverified numbers.",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21608",
    "status": 400
}

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I have verified that the destination phone number is correct.
Checked Geo Permissions in my Twilio settings, ensuring the region is enabled.
Confirmed that my phone can receive international SMS.
Checked other inboxes and message folders (including spam).
Despite these efforts, the verification SMS is not sent, and the error persists when trying to send SMS to my registered number. Additionally, testing repeatedly like this seems to deduct trial balance, which is frustrating.

Questions:

Why am I not receiving the verification SMS for new phone numbers?
Is there something specific I missed in the Twilio trial setup?
How can I resolve the 21608 error and successfully send test SMS using a trial
account?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


I'm sorry to hear you are having difficulties. It sounds to me that you do everything right. Sometimes carriers block SMS, especially when your receiving phone number is from an uncommon country. Can you confirm which country code your number has? And have you tried it with another number from friends that maybe have a different country code?
